# Why is the Pay rent Method Not working Correctly?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

Ok so I have two Classes: One for Players and One for Properties.

```
public class Player {
int money = 1500;
Object NamePlayer;
String Names;
ArrayList properties = new ArrayList(15);

public Player(String Name) {
    Names = Name;

}      
public void recieve(int ammount){
    money = money + ammount;
}
public void payment(int ammount){
    money = money - ammount;
}
public void addProperty(Property name){
    if (name.Value > money){
        System.out.println("Sorry, You dont have enough money!");
    }else{
        money -= name.Value;
        properties.add(name.Name);
        name.setOwner(this, name);
    }    
}
```

and Property class

```
public class Property {
String Name;
int Value;
int House1Value;
int House2Value;
int House3Value;
int House4Value;
int Hotel1Value;
int Hotel2Value;
int Hotel3Value;
int Hotel4Value;
int Houses;
int Hotels;
int Rent;
Object Owner;

public Property(int value, int houses, int hotel, int rent, 
        int house1,int house2,int house3,int house4, int hotel1,
        int hotel2,int hotel3,int hotel4, String names){

    Value = value;
    Houses = houses;
    Hotels = hotel;
    Rent = rent;
    House1Value = house1;
    House2Value = house2;
    House3Value= house3;
    House4Value= house4;
    Hotel1Value= hotel1;
    Hotel2Value= hotel2;
    Hotel3Value= hotel3;
    Hotel4Value= hotel4;
    Name = names;

}
public int addHotel(int numHotel){

    if (Hotels < 4){
    Hotels += numHotel;
    return Hotels;  
    }else{
       System.out.println("Sorry, You must Purchase more Houses to do that.");
    }
    return 2;
 }
public int addHouse(int numHouse){
    if (Houses < 4){
        Houses += numHouse;
    }else{
        Houses = Houses;
    }

    return Houses;
}
public int determineRent(int numHouse, int numHotel){
    if (numHotel == 4){
        Rent += Hotel4Value;
    }else if (numHotel ==3){
        Rent += Hotel3Value;
    }else if (numHotel == 2){
        Rent += Hotel2Value;
    }else if (numHotel == 1){
        Rent += Hotel1Value;
    }else if (numHouse == 4){
        Rent += House4Value;
    }else if (numHouse == 3){
        Rent += House3Value;
    }else if (numHouse == 2){
        Rent += House2Value;
    }else{
        Rent = Rent + House1Value;
    }
    return Rent;
}
public void setOwner(Player owner, Property property){
    Owner = owner.Names;
```

And then my main Java File looks like this

```
public class Monopoly {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Player Bob = new Player("Bob");
    Player John = new Player("John");
    Property Boardwalk = new Property(400,0,0,400,600,0,0,0,0,0,0,1000,"Boardwalk");
    showMoney(Bob);
    showMoney(John);
    Bob.addProperty(Boardwalk);
    System.out.println(Boardwalk.Owner);
    showRent(Boardwalk);
    payRent(John, Bob, Boardwalk);
    showMoney(John);
    showMoney(Bob);
    showRent(Boardwalk);
}
public static void showMoney(Player player){
    System.out.println(player.Names + " 's current balance is $" + player.money);
}
public static void showProperties(Player player){
    System.out.println(player.Names + " owns " + player.properties);
}
public static void showRent(Property property){
    System.out.println(property.determineRent(property.Houses, property.Hotels));
}
public static void payRent(Player player1, Player player2, Property property){
    if(property.Owner == player2.Names){
    player1.payment(property.determineRent(property.Houses, property.Hotels));
    player2.recieve(property.determineRent(property.Houses, property.Hotels));
    }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry " + player2.Names + " does not own " + property.Name + "!");
    }
}
```

The Question is. Why When i run this program i get the following:

Bob 's current balance is $1500
John 's current balance is $1500
Bob
1000
John 's current balance is $-100
Bob 's current balance is $3300
2800

when i am passing the same number through to each players respective methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the method determineRent, you did not initialize the rent with 0. Therefore, on the second call to determineRent(), it starts from where it remained at the end of the previous call.